# Should I add commas anywhere within this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis

Our expert services range from preparing proposals of best practice designs to value added engineering service for post-bid projects to field service start-up.

Comment: What exactly does it mean? It is quite ambiguous and vague, and the confusing use of preposition makes it almost entirely incomprehensible. What kind of proposals do you prepare exactly? Range from proposals to what—value-added engineering services, or field-service start-up? And what _are_ half those things supposed to be to begin with?

Comment: I think I just won buzzword bingo.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which phrases modify which other phrases.  You can't just pepper commas into a sentence and expect it to make things clear.  You need to know how they relate to one another.

If, as I suspect, you are saying you offer both proposals AND engineering services AND field service start-up, you would say:

> Our expert services range from preparing proposals of best practice designs[COMMA] to value added engineering service for post-bid projects[COMMA] to field service start-up.

Though that really is pretty cumbersome as-is.  You may just want to dedicate a paragraph to stating the quality of each service you're offering.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is verbose and could definitely use a few commas. If you are using this sentence in a brochure I would recommend breaking it to smaller sentences.

> Our expert services range from preparing proposals of best practice designs, to value added engineering service for post-bid projects, to field service start-up.

Comment: While I agree the sentence needs simplifying to be understandable, the commas in your suggestion make it entirely incomprehensible and make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I reviewed your comment and have fixed it to sound like a list;which I assume addresses your concern.

Answer (score -1):

You should write this as a list:

> Our expert services range from:
>
> - preparing proposals of best practice designs to
> - value added engineering service for post-bid projects to
> - field service start-up.

Instead of "range from", consider using "include" and removing the errant "to"s at the end of each line-item.

---

As a list, these important facets will each stand with more significance and attention.